# Trying to get property of non-object issue with associating

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to post a new thread in one of my forums through a create and store form and keep encountering an error when trying to associate the thread with the forum i'm posting the thread inside. Anyone know where the issue is?

issue:

```
Trying to get property of non-object
at HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'Trying to get property of non-object', 'ThreadController.php', 51, array('request' => object(Request), 'forum_id' => 'soccer', 'forum' => null, 'thread' => object(Thread)))
```

Controller:

```
public function create($slug)
{
    //
    $forum = Forum::where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();

    return view('threads.create')->withForum($forum);
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request, $forum_id)
{
    //
    $this->validate($request, array(
        'threadname' => 'required|max:90',
        'post' => 'required|max:99000'
    ));
    $forum = Forum::find($forum_id);
    $thread = new Thread();
    $thread->threadname = $request->threadname;
    $thread->forums()->associate($forum);
    $thread->user_id = $request->user()->id;
    $thread->save();


    return view('forum.index');

}
```

View:

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['thread.store', $forum->slug], 'method' => 'POST', 'files' => 'true']) !!}
   {!! Form::label('threadname', 'Title of Thread:') !!}
   {!! Form::text('threadname', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
  {!! Form::label('post', 'Message:') !!}
  {!! Form::textarea('post', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
  {!! Form::submit('Create', array('class' => 'btn-send btn-lg btn-block')) !!}
  {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. If you believe your question is not useful or is no longer useful, it should be *deleted* instead of editing out all of the data that actually makes it a question. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the CC BY-SA 3.0 license). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Comment: Delete me and my post

Comment: @detinu20 If you want to be disassociated from this post, then please see [this relevant meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/how-do-i-remove-my-name-from-a-post-in-accordance-with-cc-by-sa-3-0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to find a forum using the string `soccer`, this should be the id of of the forum.

`'forum_id' => 'soccer'`

`$forum = Forum::find($forum_id);`

if you're searching by slug or title you can't use `find()`